# Setting an Item Delegate for rows in a QTreeView when the tree is dynamic

Tags: qt, treeview

I am using a QTreeView to display a hierarchy of items.  Something like this

```
Child 1
Child 2
Child 3
   Child a
   Child b
   Child c
Child 4
   Child d
```

The trick is this:  The children of Child 3, and Child 4 is a dynamic list.  So there can be any number of children under either.   I also want to be able to rename each of the nodes, but there are different rules of what is a correct name for the children of Child 3, and Child 4.

I started setting setItemDelegateForRow, but of course that doesn't work, as the children shift up and down in the tree as others are added/removed.

I was hoping there was a way to attribute an ItemDelegate to a QStandardItem, but it doesn't seem possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of investigation and thinking, we found a solution that's not horrible.

We add a check when the selection changes in the tree, and depending on the selection we call setItemDelegate() and pass the desired Delegate for the selected node in the tree.